# Example tablespcae in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I need to know why example table space is created by Oracle 11g ? Does it effects the performance if it is full ? if yes how can we stop it being used ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you please be a bit more specific? What is the name of this example tablespace? Click on the [edit] link and add more details to your question. Refrain from using screen shots if possible and instead script out the DDL for the tablespaces in question. Thanks.

Comment: /opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/srvm/admin/clustdb.sql:CREATE TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" LOGGING DATAFILE '/dev/vx/rdsk/oracle_dg/clustdb_raw_example_160m' SIZE 140M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;

Comment: Why did you install an old version of Oracle? I've never heard of the EXAMPLES tablespace on 11g. 21c ATP? Yes. But not 11g.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - the DDL you posted in a comment would be _much_ easier to read if you had edited your question and posted it there as formatted text.  That said - first, the size or utilization of a TS does not affect performance.  Are you seeing performance issues?  Second, you could always query DBA_SEGMENTS to see what is in the TS.  If it is nothing but examples that you don't need, you could DROP the objects and the TS.

Comment: @EdStevens, I think you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - sorry, I didn't notice that you weren't the OP.   so, what _was_ the point of posting DDL for a TS?  I'm missing how that addressed the OP's question.

Comment: @EdStevens in case anyone was wondering - eg. the people that had never heard of it - when the example tablespace was created, I wanted to show where that happened.  IMHO Oracle doesn't create it unless a DBA requests it, have a look at the flie location, I don't have any /dev/vx.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - Ah.. Ok, I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tablespace is just a logical set of data files. It is ok for data files to be full; this will not affect performance unless you add data to a full tablespace. At that point you may have to wait for a data file to grow according to its autoextend settings, or if it is already at its maximum allowed size you may encounter an error stating that more space was not available and the tablespace could not be extended.

Since "EXAMPLES" should contain nothing but sample data such as the "SCOTT" schema and should not be expected to grow, it should not directly affect the performance of your database. If you are running backups, it *will* affect the size of your backup sets, but that is all.